# Factor analysis in Market Research

Tags: factor-analysis, survey, likert, marketing

I am doing a survey to find out customer experience/satisfaction for  a specific product. My  survey contains a scaling  question in which i asked satisfaction level (from 1 to 5) 5 being very satisfied with respect to various attributes(15 in number) of the product. Now i am confused about how to analyze these results. I want to use a statistical technique for  analysis.I came to know about factor analysis. Is it applicable here? 
If yes then how to interpret final results of factor analysis to say something about satisfaction level.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Factorial Analysis is especially helpful when trying to visualize a high-dimension space (*i.e* dataset with lots of variables). In your case, that could be somewhat applicable. Factorial Analysis, such as PCA, is strictly speaking not compatible with ordinal variables (as it assumes that your variables are linear, and thus continuous) but lots of people in sensometrics still use it in your situation.

Using PCA you could visualize more easily how your individuals and variables 'behave' with one another. Meaning that you could see which variables hold the same information.

If you want to specifically explain which variables have an impact on satisfaction level (and even quantify that impact) then I would recommend linear modeling (such as ANOVA if all your attributes are factors).

Comment: So i was reading about Fa and PCA both.  End results in both cases are factor loadings of Rotated Matrix. Its clear that factor loadings are used to group variables with different factors. Can loadings be used for any other interpretation related to satisfaction level?  
What i want  after reducing the size of variables is that i should be able to tell some info like this -from what factors  customers are satisfied the most and what factors need improvements.

Comment: Well with PCA you could tell that for exemple a strong sweet taste is correlated with high levels of satisfaction or on the contrary that high Bitterness score are correlated with low levels of satisfaction. But if you want to have a clear idea of the 'quantitative' impact of each variable on the satisfaction level you should use modeling. That way you will be able to tell how much a given variable contribute to statisfaction level and if your model is good enough you could even try to predict the optimum for statifaction level.

Comment: So what i m thinking is to first use  Fa/PCA for data reduction and to remove multicollinearity ad then apply regression model. Should i try this approach?

Comment: Regression in the sense that i have asked overall satisfaction question also.

Comment: Yeah that sounds like a good approach. Something you might experience with your PCA is having all your variables correlated in the same manner to your dimensions which visually would translate as having all your variables in the same quarter of your correrlations circle. If you have that then it is what we call * effet taille* (sorry I don't have a clue about what you call it in english) and in sensometrics you often just have to use adjusted means to get rid of it.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a structural model, e.g., the impact of customer experience (CX) on customer satisfaction, you could use PLS-SEM based analysis. A full guideline is available in this open-access article including the latest [survey questions for customer satisfaction](https://doi.org/10.1016/j.jretai.2022.03.003), customer experience, customer loyalty, trust, and share-of-wallet. (also see the web appendix of the article for details).